# Google maps -- pop up box

Tags: google-maps, kml, popupwindow

I have converted multiple shapefiles to KML using the Shp2kml2 software from Zonums Solutions. I have made a map with the KML layers (of which I have imported to google docs to get the url). As an example:

```
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B15UI5xGYTOadDlta2FoZ2pCc1E&export=download'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

When I click on a polygon layer in google maps, the pop-up box opens. How can I make it so that when I click on a second polygon layer, the pop-up box that was selected earlier is automatically cleared and not shown anymore? (Because in my situation, the earlier pop-up box still shows up but I don't want this to happen because if the user selects multiple polygon layers, there would be too many pop-up box on the screen. I understand that the user can select X to delete the pop-up window but I would like to make it as user-friendly as possible).

In addition to the polygon layers, I have other point layers in the map. But when I try to click on a specific point, the pop-up information is that of the polygon which rests in the same place as the points.

My map is found in: http://userpages.flemingc.on.ca/~catam/collab.html

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. You probably want to suppress the native infowindow and create your own infowindow opened by a click listener on all the layers that you want to have infowindows.

Comment: @geocodezip, our online map created so far is: userpages.flemingc.on.ca/~catam/collab.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider the following approach:

1)suppress a *default* info window:

```
   var kmlOptions = {
           suppressInfoWindows: true,  // do not to display an info window when clicked
           preserveViewport: false,
           map: map
       };
   var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, kmlOptions);
```

2)register a *shared* instance of [Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow):

```
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var openInfoWindow = function (KMLevent) {
    infoWindow.close();
    infoWindow.setOptions(
    {
        content: KMLevent.featureData.infoWindowHtml,
        position: KMLevent.latLng,
        pixelOffset: KMLevent.pixelOffset
    });
    infoWindow.open(map);
};
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", openInfoWindow);
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/6b7b7cy3/)**